# Pagination to a different template

Tags: pagination

I have a blog with a different header on the home page, than the other pages. I would like to show the latest blog posts on the homepage and paginate after 10 posts to the next paginated page, using the standard header design (which is different than on the homepage).

Is there a way I can accomplish this in Craft using the paginate function, or das paginated content always has the use the same template design?

Thanks for your help. markus

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the setBasePath() function of the paginate component to change the base URL

I.e

```
{% paginate query as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
{% do pageInfo.setBasePath('new_url') %}
```